# Creating Counter that adjusts based on category

Tags: ms-access, count, counter, iif-function

`SELECT Table1.DateBEG, Table1.DateEND, Table2.[HIRE DATE], Table2.Action, Table2.EffectiveDate, IIf([Table2].[HIRE DATE]<=[table1].[action] And [Table2].[Field4]<>"LOA",1,0) AS expr1 FROM Table1, Table2;`

I have two Tables as you can see in the images below. One containing ranges, and the other containing an employee id, hire date, effective date, and action.

The idea is to have a counter that counts each range that the hire date fits in, but if there is an instance of an action with "LOA" then the counter stops counting. Only counting the ranges where an effective Date with action LOA isn't present.

My code above doesn't entirely work as it still includes date ranges which include LOA. In the table, the ranges which should count is the second only with the third and first not counting as the first is before the hire date and the thrid range contains an instance of LOA in the date range. If anyone can assist me, it would be much appreciated!

[image: Table1] [image: Table2]

Comment: If you had a query, even if it did not work, it is best to post what you had anyway.  That reveals in a concise, direct format at least nearly what you want and perhaps shows others what concept needs clarification so that you can better write your own queries in the future.  Also, please edit the question and format the data in a better way.  You can click the help icon (?) at the top right of the question text editor.  Usually you can format data as code with proper spacing.  Some users will come along and do this for you, but it's best if you learn how to do it also.

Comment: `SELECT Table1.DateBEG, Table1.DateEND, Table2.[HIRE DATE], Table2.Action, Table2.EffectiveDate, IIf([Table2].[HIRE DATE]<=[table1].[action] And [Table2].[Field4]<>"LOA",1,0) AS expr1
FROM Table1, Table2;`

Comment: Table 1 contains the columns Date BEG and Date end to establish a range. Table 2 contains a name, hire date, action, and effective date. My thinking is to count the amount of ranges where hire date fits in, but if the action is LOA then the count is 0. Technically what I want is a counter that counts up each time the Hire date fits in the range, but the moment the action is LOA the counter stops until the next date range which the effective date of LOA doesn't fit in.

Comment: Please edit and format the actual question.  Adding this detail in the comments makes it even less readable.

Comment: I can guess that `Field1` is `DateBEG` and that `Field2` is `DateEND` and that `Field4` is `Action`, but I cant guess what `table1.Action` is. I see that `[HIRE DATE]` is compared to that field, but I can't see where you check whether `[HIRE DATE]` "fits" in an *interval*. There are multiple *actions* for a single employee, so you want to count each interval multiple times (for "HIR" and for "ACT" *actions*), right? A **counter** provides a continuous numbering. I can't see the attempt to implement such, I only see a field you can **count** using a `SUM` aggregate function. Please clarify.

Comment: By fits in I mean, if the hire date is <= field2 [Date End]. I don't want to count it multiple times per action is the issue. The idea is to count the number of ranges where hire date is less than or equal to the date end. Part of my trouble is that because of multiple actions under a single employee I get extra counts. So if hire date is <= two end dates, because there are three actions under the same employee it becomes 6.

Comment: I was attempting making a sequential number system that goes 1234 per empl id, but I'm unsure how to achieve this. So I've decided instead to simply work based on a specific action, but I have two criteria. If HIR is there sumiif based on the effective date for that. However if ACT is there then sumiif based on effective date of that. Any ideas as to how to do this switch?

Comment: Calculating row number is a common topic. Review https://accessexperts.com/blog/2015/07/28/ways-to-do-sequential-numbering-in-access/

Comment: You want to select effective date for an employee based on whether or not there is a record with ACT? Selecting a record based on value in another record of same table is not easy. Requires nested query or domain aggregate such as DLookup. These queries can perform very slowly with large datasets.

Comment: Achieving what you want might require multiple progressive queries. Post example of desired output.